# Class "Route" not found after removing the configuration cache file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I ran

> php artisan config:clear

Now, i am trying to run

> php artisan serve

but it returns below error

> Class "Route" not found in `app.php` at line 5.

What should I do? Thanks for your answering.

Comment: Post the exact error please with image, it usually leads you to the file where the error is happening

Comment: Did you delete your vendor folder?

Answer (score 0):

Check your app.php file in  'aliases' array this code exists or not

'Route'=> "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route",

Comment: I have app.php file in the only bootstrap files. And there is not that kind of thing in that file.

Comment: There is config folder in your Laravel project ,there is app.php file

Comment: No it didn't work. I think the *artisan* can be the problem. Because `php artisan` also turned same error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `config.php` from `bootstrap` folder

Then run the following three commands...

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```